# The space above and below the legend using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

If you look at the charts [here](http://markthegraph.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/credit-aggregates-july-2012.html)! you can see there is a lot of white space above and below the legend. I wish to reduce the amount of space.

Example code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(reshape)
library(plyr)
library(scales)

theme_set(theme_bw())

rows <- 1:nrow(faithful)
data <- cbind(faithful, rows)
molten <- melt(data, id.vars='rows', measure.vars=c('eruptions', 'waiting'))

p <- ggplot() +
    geom_line(data=molten, 
        mapping=aes(x=rows, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable), size=0.8) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c('red','blue')) +
    opts(title='Title') +
    xlab(NULL) + ylab('Meaningless Numbers') +
    opts(
        legend.position='bottom',
        legend.direction='horizontal',
        legend.title=theme_blank(),
        legend.key=theme_blank(),
        legend.text=theme_text(size=9),
        legend.margin = unit(0, "line"),
        legend.key.height=unit(0.6,"line"),      
        legend.background = theme_rect(colour='white', size=0)
    )

ggsave(p, width=8, height=4, filename='crap.png', dpi=125)
```

Answer (score 16):

To remove the margins of the legend (negative values reduce the white space even more):

```
p + theme(legend.margin=margin(t=0, r=0, b=0, l=0, unit="cm"))
p + theme(legend.margin=margin(t=0, r=0, b=-0.5, l=0, unit="cm"))
```

You can also remove the lower part of the plot margin by specifying negative numbers (but make sure that you don't cut off your legend):

```
p + theme(plot.margin = unit(x = c(0, 0, -0.2, 0), units = "cm"))
```

Illustrations: [ggplot2, legend on top and margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073772/ggplot2-legend-on-top-and-margin)

Comment: Also `legend.box.margin` in `theme`, as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41362895/r-ggplot2-change-the-spacing-between-the-legend-and-the-panel

Answer (score 5):

Here are two additional options that allow you to shrink the space surround the legend:

```
p + theme(
      legend.key.height=unit(0, "cm"),      
      plot.margin = unit(c(1,0.5,0,0.5), "lines")
    )
```

The option `plot.margin` describes how much space there is around the plot itself. The third argument describes the amount of space below the plot.  Setting that to zero helps.

[image]

Comment: So fundamentally, you are telling me there is apdding around the legend I cannot get rid of? I can only make some of it look like its not there.

Comment: I'm not saying there is padding you can't get rid of. I'm just saying that my solution is the best I could do. No doubt somebody else can do better.