# ggplot2, legend on top and margin

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

Consider the following:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + 
  geom_bar() +   
  theme(
    plot.margin=unit(x=c(0,0,0,0),units="mm"),
    legend.position="top",
    plot.background=element_rect(fill="red")) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title.position="top"))
```

The output of that looks something like this:
[image: ggplot2 output]
In the context of `plot.margin=unit(x=c(0,0,0,0),units="mm")` there's an unseemly amount of white (red) space above the legend. Does anyone know how to remedy that?

Thanks for any hint.

Sincerely, Joh

Comment: Great question, just lost an hour to this trying to work out why legend.margin of 0 didn't appear to be working. The love/hate ggplot relationship continues!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Like you said, I can't see it in your example, but I'm guessing the margin is of the legend itself. You can eliminate the margin around the legend itself by adding:

```
+ theme(legend.margin=margin(t = 0, unit='cm'))
```

This applies to ggplot2 v2.1.0 or higher. Note that, at least for now, the old solution still works as well:

```
+ theme(legend.margin=unit(-0.6,"cm")) # version 0.9.x
```

[image]

Comment: And there is a margin for the panel too (`panel.margin`) and setting all to zero would still leave some extra space on the top. If you insist on eliminating those, you might pass **negative** numbers as `unit`s, e.g.: `theme(plot.margin = unit(x = c(-5, 0, 0, 0), units = "mm")`

Comment: Changed the background in the example to illustrate the issue. Neither `panel.margin` nor `legend.margin` have any effect.

Comment: I realize this isn't an exact solution to your problem, but why don't you position the legend inside the plot window instead? If you have a lot of free space somewhere in the plot window, you could put the legend there. With this example dataset, `theme(legend.position=c(0.9,0.8))` places the legend in the upper right corner.

Comment: Actually, `theme(legend.margin=unit(-0.6,"cm"))` all but eliminates the margin. I'll adjust my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, but that's possibly not generalizable ... there may be scale factors etc. and fine tuning this for every plot is not particularly satisfying. The in-plot solution also does not work in my actual case (I used an example from ggplot2's documentation for simplicity's sake here).

Comment: @sc_evans `unit(-1, "line")` is probably closer to the truth according to my investigations below.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. @balin -- might that be the generalizable answer you're looking for?

Comment: Works ok now. Have build a ggplot2 version check into my code in the hope that future versions will make `guide.margin` available ...

Comment: This changed to ``theme(legend.margin=margin(t = -0.5, unit='cm'));``

Comment: Thanks @user3096626. Though a minor addendum: `t = -0.5` will push the legend title out of view. I've edited the answer to include the v2.1.0+ solution.

Answer (score 14):

If I exaggerate the margins for more visibility, and run showViewports, I get the following:

```
p + guides(fill=guide_legend(keyheight=unit(1,"cm"))) + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm"))
showViewport(col="black",label=TRUE, newpage=TRUE, leaves=FALSE)
```

[image]

from which it would appear that the non-existent title is somehow taking space.

**Edit:** nope, it's just an unfortunate overlap of the labels. It's not the title.

Let's look at the legend itself, which seems to be causing the problem.

```
library(gtable)
g = ggplotGrob(p)
leg = gtable_filter(g, "guide")
plot(leg)
leg$heights
# sum(0.5lines, sum(1.5mm, 10mm, 0mm, 1.5mm), 0.5lines)+0cm
grid.rect(height=leg$heights) 
grid.rect(height=leg$heights - unit(1,"line"), gp=gpar(lty=2))
```

so, indeed, it's the legend that's adding some margins (0.5 + 0.5 = 1 line in total). I reckon it's a missing `guide.margin` [option in the theme](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/blob/master/R/guides-.r#L228), that is being replaced by a default value of half a line.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm ... neither setting title explicitly to NULL nor setting it's element_text's size and/or line height to 0 brings any gain ... any further ideas?

Comment: i was on the wrong track. I've added further hints that now point at the legend instead.

Comment: and posted a [bug report on github](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/819)

Comment: @baptiste: Do you know how to wrap the legend title to two lines?

Answer (score 9):

In the year since this question was asked/answered, ggplot entered maintenance mode, so there won't be any future updates (meaning the OP's [strategy of waiting for an update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073772/ggplot2-legend-on-top-and-margin#comment24696556_17074144) won't work).

The accepted answer relies on fudging the margin around the legend with `legend.margin`. However, this doesn't generalize well, especially when using `ggsave()` with different sizes or scale factors. There is fortunately a more generalizable, universal solution, though.

`legend.margin` only takes a single value for padding on all sides, while `plot.margin` takes four values for the top, right, bottom, and left margins. The default margins are based on lines (rather than mm or inches), like so: `plot.margin=unit(c(c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5)), units="line")`

If you set `legend.margin` to 0, you can use negative `plot.margin` values, based on line units, to move the legend to the edge of the plot area. Setting the top margin to -0.5 works perfectly:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + 
  geom_bar() +   
  theme(
    plot.margin=unit(c(-0.5, 1, 0.5, 0.5), units="line"),
    legend.position="top",
    plot.background=element_rect(fill="red"),
    legend.margin=unit(0, "lines")) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title.position="top"))
```

[image: Correct legend on top]

The same idea works if the legend is positioned at the bottom:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + 
  geom_bar() +   
  theme(
    plot.margin=unit(c(1, 1, -0.5, 0.5), units="line"),
    legend.position="bottom",
    plot.background=element_rect(fill="red"),
    legend.margin=unit(0, "lines")) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title.position="top"))
```

[image: Correct legend on bottom]

**As long as you set the margin of interest to -0.5 lines, the extra whitespace should disappear.** This should work at any viewport size and any width/height/scale combination with `ggsave()`

Comment: While this solution certainly reduces the distance between the legend and top viewport border, making the legend closer to the main plot seems impossible. I tried to fiddle with parameters, but cannot reach the solution that worked pre-2.1.0. `legend.key.height=unit(0, "cm")` reduces the distance and works for top/bottom legends yet the little gap introduced by something remains.