# How to remove extra space left by setting "theme(legend.title = element_blank())“ in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, title, legend

there!

I want to remove legend title in ggplot2. I used legend.title = element_blank(), but there is still some extra space at the top of the legend box where the legend title originally was. Actually, I don't want that space. Anyone has ideas how to solve it? Thanks!

Here is the code to replicate the unwanted extra space:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
df1 <- data.frame(
  sex = factor(c("Female","Female","Male","Male")),
  time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner","Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
  total_bill = c(13.53, 16.81, 16.24, 17.42)
)

# A basic graph
lp <- ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, group=sex, shape=sex)) + geom_line() + geom_point()

lp + theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
           legend.background = element_rect(colour = "black", size = 0.1),
           legend.key.size = unit(0.4, "lines"))
```

the code snippet is taken from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/ with a little modification.
The extra space exists between the first legend key and the top border of the legend box. I think it's because I resize the key size. When I remove `legend.key.size = unit(0.4, "lines"), everything is fine. However, I want to keep that line in my specific figure. I'm not sure if there is any way to solve that problem.

Comment: do you have any code...explicitly showing anything you've tried?

Comment: There is slightly more space on the top than the bottom, but it is not because of resizing the key. If you add , e.g., `fill = "red"` to `legend.background = element_rect()` it is easier to see that this is at any size (and that `legend.title = element_blank()` indeed removes the title space vs adding a blank title with `""`, which retains the space). You should mention that you have taken the plot example from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/ and also that one needs to run `library(grid)` to use `unit()`.

Comment: @LJW Thank you for your comments. I add the url and library(grid) now. Do you mean that there is no way to reduce the space at the top?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible - I imagine it must be somehow. Unfortunately this is beyond my skill level. This might be helpful in narrowing down where the space comes from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17074720/3267983.

Answer (score 6):

This is my first answer ever.
theme(legend.margin=margin(t=-0.25,l=0.05,b=0.0,r=0.05, unit='cm'))
The negative moves the space inwards.

Answer (score -1):

how about

```
p + theme(legend.position="none")
```

where `p` is the ggplot.

Comment: That will remove the entire legend, OP wants to keep the legend but remove the title and especially the empty space it leaves behind.